# «Пусть счастье тебя наполняет» или «пусть счастьем тебя наполняет»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-варианта

Как правильно написать?

*Пусть **счастье** тебя наполняет.

Пусть **счастьем** тебя наполняет.*

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать первый вариант, то не хватает действующего лица, которое бы "тебя наполняло счастьем", поэтому грамотнее будет сказать:"пусть счастьем наполнишься ты". Во втором варианте счастье выступает в роли действующего лица и не хватает дополнения, к примеру такого:"пусть счастье тебя наполняет собой".